# what's the meaning of <step> in xsl:variable?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have no idea about "step" in `xsl:variable` . I would appreciate if any one can explain "step".

The following XSLT just include 2 elements in root element.

`xsl:output` define the output format;
`xsl:variable` define the variable ;

How this code be parsed? what does this code stand for?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  version="2.0"
  extension-element-prefixes="saxon">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

  <!-- <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"
    encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/> -->

  <xsl:variable name="processes">
    <!-- exclude elements with @specific-use='print-only' -->
    <step>prep/jpub3-webfilter.xsl</step>
    <!-- format citations in NLM/PMC format -->
    <step>citations-prep/jpub3-PMCcit.xsl</step>
    <!-- convert into HTML for display -->
    <step>main/jpub3-html.xsl</step>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:include href="main/shell-utility.xsl"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Supplement "shell-utility.xsl"

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  version="2.0"
  extension-element-prefixes="saxon">

  <!-- This stylesheet does not stand alone! It is a component
       to be called into XSLT 2.0 shell stylesheets. -->

  <xsl:variable name="document" select="/" saxon:assignable="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="runtime-params">
    <base-dir>
      <xsl:value-of
        select="replace(base-uri(/), '/[^/]+$','')"/>     
    </base-dir>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$processes/step/concat('../',.)">
      <xsl:message>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;... Applying </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:message>
      <saxon:assign name="document"
        select="saxon:transform(
                  saxon:compile-stylesheet(doc(.)),
                  $document,
                  $runtime-params/* )"/>
      <!-- A third argument to saxon:transform could specify
           runtime parameters for any (or all) steps -->
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:sequence select="$document"/>
    <xsl:message>&#xA;... Done</xsl:message>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

The code just creates a variable called `processes` and assigns it a node list containing the three `<step>` elements.  The `<step>` elements have no meaning in themselves as far as the XSL parser is concerned.

Comment: In XSLT2 variables are very general and can contain an XML node-list/tree fragment.

Answer (score 1):

> what does this code stand for?
>
> ```
>  <xsl:variable name="processes">     
>   <!-- exclude elements with @specific-use='print-only' -->     
>   <step>prep/jpub3-webfilter.xsl</step>     
>   <!-- format citations in NLM/PMC format -->     
>   <step>citations-prep/jpub3-PMCcit.xsl</step>     
>   <!-- convert into HTML for display -->     
>   <step>main/jpub3-html.xsl</step>   
>  </xsl:variable>
> ```

This is a definition of a global variable named `processes` and of type `document-node()` -- its value is a temporary tree that contains three `step` elements that are children of the document node.

How this variable is used depends on the code of the included stylesheet module that resides at:
`main/shell-utility.xsl`. Because this code isn't provided , nothing can be said about the real usage of the `processes` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have upload the shell-utility.xsl code

Comment: Using this xlst to transform xml to html by saxon,the terminal show error " Error in expression $processes/step/concat('../',.): Unexpected token [<function>] in path expression". It seems something wrong.

Comment: The path `$processes/step/concat('../',.)` is wrong - `concat()` is a function, and as such it cannot be used as part of a path. I am not sure what is the intended result here, so I cannot say how to fix it.